# ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found! on ySQL Community Server GPL mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

I `5.5.36-cll MySQL Community Server` GPL mysql

When I try to `start/stop/restart` mysql server `(/etc/init.d/mysqld restart)`

I get this error:

```
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file ([FAILED]/mysql/mysqld.pid).
```

Comment: First check mysql error log to see what happened: less /var/log/mysql/error.log and scroll down to bottom or Shift+g

Comment: Check this: http://linuxadministrator.pro/blog/?p=225